# Google Sheets statically hyperlink a Cell to another tab - Cell text is formed by a using a Formula

Tags: hyperlink

I'm working with Google Sheets but run into a weird issue.

I have a cell say A10 which uses a formula CONCATENATE other cell text A1..A9 etc., to form this cell A10 text.
I'd like to statically hyperlink this cell text to another tab in the same sheet.
I don't see an ready option in Google Sheets menu to do this.
Is there a trick/alternative for this.

There is no option in Google Sheets for this.